# Can Azure Data Catalog be used to connect to on-premise databases and ingest metadata? If yes, is data profiling available?

Tags: sql-server, hybrid, azure-data-catalog, on-premises-instances

Most of the data that we would need to learn about and document in Azure Data Catalog currently resides on Premise in SQL Server databases.

Can Azure Data Catalog connect to these data sources, and serve-up metadata for data assets that are NOT stored in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

The majority of our data sources are on-premises so the answer is, yes! Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-catalog/data-catalog-dsr for details.